# Access specific object in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, action

I am making two Color Picker Box. by this two Color Picker box, i am changing the color particular movie Clip. I am used Following Code:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
     color_picker(i)
}
var colorBox:ColorPicker;
var mc:MovieClip=  new MovieClip()
addChild(mc)

function color_picker(p)
{
    colorBox = new ColorPicker();
    mc.addChild(colorBox);
    colorBox.x = 0
    colorBox.y =  p * 40;
    p++;
    colorBox.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, changeColor1)
 }

var colorTransform1:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
function changeColor1(Event:ColorPickerEvent)
{
     var color = "0x" +Event.currentTarget.selectedColor.toString(16);
     colorTransform.color = color;
     cards.getChildAt(0).transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
}
```

By this I am only Access last Color Picker Box.
please Guide me

Answer (score 0):

because you modify the colorBox pointer when you say

```
 colorBox = new ColorPicker();
```

you can create an array, and store all your colorPickers there, (or as a not so nice, but easier solution, try defining colorBox1, and colorBox2.)

```
function color_picker(p)  {
    array.push(new ColorPicker())
    colorBox = array[array.length-1]
    mc.addChild(colorBox);
    colorBox.x = 0
    colorBox.y =  p * 40;
    p++;
    colorBox.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, changeColor1)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mc:MovieClip=  new MovieClip()
addChild(mc)
for (var i:int = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    color_picker(i)
}
function color_picker(p)
{
    var colorBox = new ColorPicker();
    mc.addChild(colorBox);
    colorBox.x = 0
    colorBox.y =  p * 40;
    //p++; //NO NEED TO INCREMENT THIS VALUE, IT'S GETTING FROM THE LOOP
    colorBox.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, changeColor1)
 }
var colorTransform1:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
function changeColor1(Event:ColorPickerEvent)
{
    var color = "0x" +Event.currentTarget.selectedColor.toString(16);
    colorTransform.color = color;
    cards.getChildAt(0).transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
}
```